# Can I get frame window in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I insert myscript.js in current page in chrome tab with

```
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        { file:"myscript.js"}, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "myfunction();"});
            window.close();
        });
```

Top frame has one child iframe and value of frame.length is 1.

But when I try to get window of that iframe by using frames[0] or window.frames[0], they are undefined.

Is there my mistakes or just problem of chrome extension?

Comment: How do you try to use `frames[0]`? In a content script, or in `.executeScript`?

Comment: @RobW I used frames[0] in myscript.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a know bug.....
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20773
...theres a couple of workarounds there in the comments that might help you.